# Troubleshooting DYMO Label Printer Web Service as Static Resource

Tags: lightning, webservices, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to develop the ability to print QR codes on labels for inventory management. I'm using DYMO printers which are quiquitous and have an easy to use web service with a javascript sdk:
http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.3.0.js

Here's the Error message I get when I save the js file as a static resource:
Custom Script Eval error in 'ltng:require' [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }]

Here's the Locker Console error:
Error: Cannot set property 'Aa' of undefined

I pretty printed the code and tried to hack around the code and remove the Locker Console errors one by one, but gave up after ~6 changes, as the Locker Console does not give any lines for the errors.

Any advise on how to adjust a static resource to be Locker compliant would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you find any solution for this?